# How to use display equations with psfrag?

Tags: equations, psfrag, displaystyle

I would like to include a display equation in an EPS figure using the **pstool** package. When the command for the replacement text is `$\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2$`, then it compiles fine (see the vertical axis label):

[image]

However, when I use `$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2$$`, or more generally `\begin{equation} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2 \end{equation}` I get the following error:

[image]

I can use `\displaystyle` to force the large summation (and this does work), but the question is more general (as I may want to include equations that have more complicated formatting like a `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` situation): How to use general display style equations within pstools?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}

\psfragfig{mwe}

\end{document}
```

And here is the contents of mwe.tex:

```
% Generated using matlabfrag
% Version: v0.6.16
% Version Date: 04-Apr-2010
% Author: Zebb Prime
%
%% <text>
%
\providecommand\matlabtextA{\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont\strut}%
\psfrag{013}[bc][bc]{\matlabtextA $\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2$}%
\psfrag{014}[bc][bc]{\matlabtextA Peaks}%
\psfrag{015}[tr][tr]{\matlabtextA y}%
\psfrag{016}[tl][tl]{\matlabtextA x}%
%
%% </text>
%
%% <xtick>
%
\def\matlabfragNegXTick{\mathord{\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}}}
%
\psfrag{000}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $\matlabfragNegXTick 3$}%
\psfrag{001}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $\matlabfragNegXTick 2$}%
\psfrag{002}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $\matlabfragNegXTick 1$}%
\psfrag{003}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $0$}%
\psfrag{004}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $1$}%
\psfrag{005}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $2$}%
\psfrag{006}[ct][ct]{\matlabtextA $3$}%
%
%% </xtick>
%
%% <ytick>
%
\psfrag{007}[rc][rc]{\matlabtextA $-2$}%
\psfrag{008}[rc][rc]{\matlabtextA $0$}%
\psfrag{009}[rc][rc]{\matlabtextA $2$}%
%
%% </ytick>
%
%% <ztick>
%
\psfrag{010}[cr][cr]{\matlabtextA $-5$}%
\psfrag{011}[cr][cr]{\matlabtextA $0$}%
\psfrag{012}[cr][cr]{\matlabtextA $5$}%
%
%% </ztick>
```

This was generated by using the `matlabfrag` package from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag).

Comment: `$\displaystyle ...$`  or `\parbox{3cm}{\[......\]}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the suggestion. As noted in the question I have tried \displaystyle and it does compile correctly. However, the question is more general. Say that I want to include an equation that involves more complicated (and usually written on multiple lines) formatting, e.g. a \begin{cases} environment. I need pstool to be able to handle whatever I might put inside of a generic `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's why I gave the second suggestion, for a display environment you need the parbox form. and `\[` or `\begin{align}` or whatever you need

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ahhh, I see. I have never used `\parbox` so I am unfamiliar with how I would use it. I looked up the documentation and it seems that I need to know the width beforehand (i.e your 3cm), but how do I know the width of my expression before i have seen it? Is there a rule of thumb you use to make sure the parbox is big enough to contain the contents?

Comment: It is a general rule in tex that either you are in horizontal mode for one line stuff (`\mbox`), or vertical mode (`\parbox` or the outer main  page) where you can have math displays and linebreaking but you need to know the width in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use display constructs you need to be in vertical (paragraph) mode so you need something like

```
\parbox{3cm}{\[\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2\]}
```

choosing a suitable width for your context.

Note this is not particular to `psfrag` it is a general TeX feature, for example you can not have a display environment in `\mbox` or a tabular `c` column, you need a `\parbox` or tabular `p` column for the same reason.